# Redmine 3.3.2 stopped working after Ubuntu upgrade to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-16.04, redmine

After an update of Ubuntu Server 14.04 to 16.04 Redmine 3.3.2 stopped working. Worked fine before the upgrade. I cannot see anything in the log either for Apache2, Redmine or Mysql. Not any in the system logs either.

The redmine page only list files in public directory.

Tried to update/execute the normal gem, bundle, and apt update all the dependency.

The access to mysql is also working.

Any suggestions how to solve or trace where the error is?

Comment: Are you running your Redmine using the Passenger Apache module or the Webrick server ?. Maybe after the upgrade the Apache configuration files were overwritten

Comment: Default installations are faulty if you ask me. I'd never run Redmine as root user. I suggest you dump your database, create separate user for Redmine, and save your files, then install rvm for that user, and perform Redmine upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that eventually fixed it:

Go to /usr/share/redmine-3.3.2 and execute

```
bundle install
```

Passenger and Ruby was updated and old one was removed. But the apache configurations was not updated.

Update /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.1.3/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.1.3
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/wrappers/ruby
```

Update /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gem/passenger-5.1.3/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.1.3
    PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/wrappers/ruby
    #PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
</IfModule>
```

touch /var/log/redmine/logfile.log and give 664 rights to that file.

Then restart Apache2

```
service apache2 restart
```